# uncaught typeerror: model.save() is not a function - Emberjs 1.13.8

Tags: ember.js, controller

I am new to ember.js, I am trying to save the model from another contoller where i have am able to get all the information of the model. Whenever i try to save the model using the code below

```
saveModel: function(model) {
  model.save();
},
```

I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: model.save is not a function
```

Any idea how to solve this error?

Model information is getting passed from components using `this.sendAction()`.

Comment: Please post your ember version and where you're creating the record before saving it.

Comment: Please post this code that your using to send the model from the component. It seems like the "model" your sending is not an ember model

Comment: Okay, Let me also rephrase my question. I have a model it's named product with name, notes, stock, seller details. Now, the product is associated with deals and i am trying to save the product from deals controller instead of product controller, that's where i am getting this error. So, i am getting the product information from a deal using deal.product and it's not allowing me to save

Comment: Thanks to everyone for answering this questions. Found the answer instead of model.save() need to add model.get('_internalModel').save()

Answer (score 1):

`this.sendaction()` should be *CamelCase* -> `this.sendAction()`

Check the [Ember Guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/components/handling-events/) for *Components* -> *Handling Events* to make sure you are using `this.sendAction()` correctly

Make sure by debugging that `model` is being passed correctly from the component.

Comment: Thanks. I have added sendAction() and debugged that model which is holding the model properties.

Comment: `model.save()` should be making a POST request to your backend, is it? and is the request url correct?

Comment: Yes the request URL is correct. Because I can save other model using model.save().

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error.

Using _internalModel works but is an ugly solution. My mistake was binding the model to the promise

```
this.set('prop', this.get('store').findRecord('model', id))
```

and not use

```
this.get('store').findRecord('user', this.selectedUser.id).then(function(model) {
   self.set('prop', model);
});
```

Hope that this helps someone having the same problem.